# How do I downgrade kivy from 1.9.0 to 1.7.2 on my Moto G phone?

Tags: android, kivy, qpython

Kivy has taken an upgrade to 1.9.0, and now my QPython scripts don't work. They worked OK on kivy 1.7.2 .

I also have a Nexus 7 tablet which is still using QPython (2.7) and Kivy 1.7.2 and thats working fine, and I want to maintain compatibility between devices.

I can't upgrade QPython to QPython3 because there is no kivy support (yet).

So, is it possible to back out the auto upgrade of kivy?

Thanks in advance!